# How to print value of a calculation in pandas without extra info

Tags: pandas

I have:

[image]

which returns

[image]

How do I make it so that it only returns the number, 73.6

like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append [squeeze](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) at the end of your expression

```
q1=round(100*(t.shape[0]-t.isna().sum())/t.shape[0],1).squeeze()
#                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```